# Size of page without scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, web

Hi i need get the page size without scrolls.

What´s the minimum and maximum width and height size `www.google.com` page without scrolls?

I trying `document.body.scrollHeight document.body.scrollWidth`, but the size depends of size of window of navigator...

What´s the fixed size of page using a javascript function?

Show me an example please.

Comment: You want the window's width? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width

Comment: Most pages don't have such things as "maximum size without scrollbars". And it's very non-trivial task to find out what's the minimum size, because most of the time page content is scaled when size of a viewport is changes. This question looks like OP has suffered from an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What are you **really** trying to do?

Comment: I need print page AUTO size using puppeteer

Comment: Depends on the size of the viewport and how the content in it is styled as to whether there are scrollbars or not

Comment: Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0):

Modern web design resigned from staticly defined sizing of elements in favor of relative positioning and sizing. If you really need to know the size at a given viewport (i can't thnik of possible use-case for that, perhabs you could clarify what are u trying to achieve) I would recommend parsing the sites' DOM and CSS using PHP f.e. and then design a script that finds proper sizes (absolute are easy, relative can be converted to absolute knowing relative size and viewport dimensions).

As for the scrolls I'm guessing you think about elements with overflow rather than the actual page scrolls - in this case you will have just as many answers as the number of viewers since both browser font-size and type, scaling factor (the zoom that doesn't change the viewport)  and things like that make every element relatively sized even despite of one's effort to make it staticly defined.